# if $5\nmid a$ or $5\nmid b$, then $5\nmid a^2-2b^2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, quadratic-residues

I have  a homework as follow:

if $5\nmid a$ or $5\nmid b$, then $5\nmid a^2-2b^2$.

Please help to prove it.

EDIT: MY ATTEMPT

Suppose that $5\mid a^2-2b^2$, then $a^2-2b^2=5n$,where $n\in Z$,

then $a^2-2b^2=(a+\sqrt2b)(a-\sqrt2b)=5n$,

Since 5 is a prime number, we get that $5\mid (a+\sqrt2b)$or $5\mid (a-\sqrt2b)$,

If $5\mid (a+\sqrt2b)$, then $5\mid a$ and $5\mid b$, contradiction.

If $5\mid (a-\sqrt2b)$, then $5\mid a$ and $5\mid b$, contradiction.

Thus $5\nmid a^2-2b^2$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Hint: There are only 25 possibilities for $a$ and $b$ mod 5, so this is not too tedious to prove by exhaustion. You can cut down the possibilities further by observing what $a^2$ can be modulo 5.

Comment: You can prove a stronger statement, if $gcd(a, b)=1$ then the only prime divisors of $a^2-2b^2$ are of the form $8k+1$ or $8k-1$

Comment: For this particular problem, just observe that $a^2 \equiv 0, 1, -1 mod 5$ (0, 1, -1) are the only quadratic residues modulo 5

Comment: Seriously, just spend 10 seconds looking at numerical cases of $a$ and $b$.  You don't need advanced math.  Just test out values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Your argument would seem work for $7$ in place of $5$; however, $3^2-2\cdot1^2=7$ The problem is that you need to show that $5$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ (which it happens to be).

Answer (score 4):

This is probably what Bernard intended.

The non-zero quadratic residues mod $5$ are $1$ and $4$. Plugging these into $a^2-2b^2$ gives
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&1&4&a^2\\\hline
1&4&2\\
4&3&1\\
b^2
\end{array}
$$
Since none of the entries are $0$, we get that $a^2-2b^2\not\equiv0\pmod5$ if neither $a$ nor $b$ are $0\pmod5$.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to make a table for the function $a^2-5b^2$ in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ above the horizontal line, the possible values for $a^2$; to the left of the vertical line, those for $b^2$):
$$\begin{array}{r|rrr}
&0&1&-1\\
\hline
0&0&1&-1\\1&-2&-1&2\\-1&2&-2&1
\end{array}$$
which shows the only case with $a^2-5b^2\equiv 0\mod5$ is when $a\equiv b\equiv 0\mod5$.

Comment: I assume that the axes are $a^2$ and $b^2$. Otherwise, I would expect to see $5$ columns and $5$ rows.

Comment: Yes. The problem is I can't use any LaTeX package such as _diagbox_ to be clearer. I'll add the explanation in ordinary language.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**$\ \ (ab^{-1})^2\equiv 2\,\Rightarrow\,(ab^{-1})^4\equiv 4\,$ contra little Fermat